# Как можно упростить данное лямбда выражение?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

```
private Map<String, State[]> getDocTypes(State[] state) {
    Map<String, State[]> docTypesProps = new HashMap<>();
    Settings.LIST_TYPES.getValue().stream()
        .filter(typeDoc -> !typeDoc.equals(""))
        .forEach(typeDoc -> docTypesProps.put("doc/" + typeDoc.trim(), state));
    return docTypesProps;
}
```

Массив как ни крутил, не поддается, все никак не добавляется( Если что массив это ENUM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно написать как-то так, но лучше от этого вряд ли станет:

```
return Settings.LIST_TYPES.getValue().stream()
    .map(String::trim)
    .filter(typeDoc -> !typeDoc.isEmpty())
    .map(s -> "doc/" + s)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), state));
```

в любом случае использовать `forEach` с сайд-эффектами не стоит.

Можно добавить статический метод для оборачивания предиката:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> predicate(Predicate<T> predicate) {
    return predicate;
}
```

и тогда можно написать чуть красивее фильтр:

```
return Settings.LIST_TYPES.getValue().stream()
    .map(String::trim)
    .filter(predicate(String::isEmpty).negate())
    .map(s -> "doc/" + s)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), state));
```